# Unexpected difference between char* and string with std::getenv

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I have code that looks something like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string string_from_env(std::string var) {
  std::string out = std::getenv(var.c_str());
  return out;
}

int main() {
  const char* x1 = string_from_env("TEST_HOST").c_str();
  const char* x2 = string_from_env("TEST_USER").c_str();
  const char* x3 = string_from_env("TEST_NAME").c_str();

  std::cout << x1 << " " << x2 << " " << x3 << std::endl;

  const std::string y1 = string_from_env("TEST_HOST");
  const std::string y2 = string_from_env("TEST_USER");
  const std::string y3 = string_from_env("TEST_NAME");

  std::cout << y1 << " " << y2 << " " << y3 << std::endl;
}
```

If I run

```
export TEST_HOST=host
export TEST_USER=user
export TEST_NAME=name
g++ --std=c++2a test.cc  # version 9.3.0
./a.out
```

Then the output is

```
name name name
host user name
```

Why does the `char*` version result in `x1,x2,x3` all printing `name`, while the `std::string` version works as expected?

Is there a way I can modify the `string_from_env` function so that the same code prints `host user name` instead of `name name name`?

Comment: `x1, x2, x3` are assigned to the data of temporary `std::string`s which only exist until the end of each expression.  The code therefore exhibits Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I think you should check the return value from getenv() if it is null and you pass that to string it will not be happy

Comment: @AndersK I definitely will do that in production! the above has been just edited for brevity - in this case, all environment variables are defined, and getenv does not return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str` points to memory owned by the `string` object.  When the `string` is destroyed (or even mutated in certain ways), that pointer becomes invalid.

Since the temporary `string` objects returned by `string_from_env` in your first three calls aren't immediately bound to references, they are destroyed at the end of the full expression containing the function call.  That means that `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` all become invalid immediately after being created.  Attempting to read from them will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

consider this line

```
const char* x1 = string_from_env("TEST_HOST").c_str();
```

You do not store the result of calling `string_from_env("TEST_HOST")`, so the temporary string it returns will be destroyed at the end of the expression. So `x1` will point to the inner buffer of an already destroyed string. Your code has undefined behavior.

The reason `x1`, `x2` and `x3` all point to the same string has to do with small string optimization which is an implementation detail of std::string